# Getting some build error in SE Policy while doing AOSP build

Tags: android, android-source, selinux

Please help me with these SE Linux errors:

```
[ 31% 5/16] build out/target/product/generic_arm64_ab/obj/ETC/plat_seapp_contexts_intermediates/plat_seapp_contexts
FAILED: out/target/product/generic_arm64_ab/obj/ETC/plat_seapp_contexts_intermediates/plat_seapp_contexts
/bin/bash -c "out/host/linux-x86/bin/checkseapp -p out/target/product/generic_arm64_ab/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy -o 
out/target/product/generic_arm64_ab/obj/ETC/plat_seapp_contexts_intermediates/plat_seapp_contexts   system/sepolicy/private/seapp_contexts    
vendor/dummy/michel/frameworks/Mye/sepolicy/private/seapp_contexts  vendor/dummy/michel/frameworks/core/sepolicy/private/seapp_contexts 
 vendor/dummy/michel/frameworks/Mye/sepolicy/private/seapp_contexts  vendor/dummy/services/sepolicy/private/seapp_contexts"
Error: Duplicate line detected in file: vendor/dummy/michel/frameworks/Mye/sepolicy/private/seapp_contexts
Lines 1 and 1 match on everything!
03:04:57 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (7 seconds) ####
```

Comment: What is `vendor/dummy/michel/frameworks/Mye/sepolicy/private/seapp_contexts`?

Answer (score 2):

The error message:

```
 Error: Duplicate line detected in file: 
 vendor/dummy/michel/frameworks/Mye/sepolicy/private/seapp_contexts
 Lines 1 and 1 match on everything!
```

... means that `seapp_contexts` has some conflicting or duplicate policy in line 1, whatever that may be. This line may also be a duplicate of the policies in the any of the other `seapp_contexts` files above... each policy must only exist once - and it must not match everything.